# In AutoLISP is it possible to get function name in function body?

Tags: lisp, autocad-plugin, autolisp

In specified conditions I want to print name of fuction in this function. but I don't know how to get it.
In C++ I can use preprocessor macro `__FUNCTION__`. I something simmilar in AutoLISP?

Comment: Does autolisp support (lisp) macros?

Comment: @DanielJour: I don't think it does (although you probably could implement a macro system for it).

Comment: I work with AutoLISP since few years, but never met lisp macros.
What You mean by macros in lisp ?  Any example?

Comment: @CADDeveloper Lisp's macros are one of the features generally considered to make it such a powerful language.  A comment is way too small for a good answer, but the point is that you can modify the source code during part of the compilation process. E.g., in Common Lisp, **with-open-file**  is a macro that turns `(with-open-file (x "/tmp/foo") ...)` into something like `(let ((x (open "/tmp/foo")) (unwind-protect (progn ...) (close x)))`.  I think the point here is that you could write a macro in Common Lisp like **defunx** that would turn `(defunx name (...) ...)` into something like...

Comment: ... `(defun name (...) (let ((__function__ 'name)) ...))`, which would give you effect similar to what you might have in C.

Comment: A quick look at the AutoLisp manual shows no obvious `defmacro`, which surprises me, because XLisp has it. The Wikipedia page for AutoLisp says "... lacking in such regular LISP features as macro system, ..." so I suspect there's no macros.

Comment: OK, so we don't have macros. But I still don't understand how macros could help with get name of function.
What is the idea we may get by macros? 
Only one I think is to define function and one of local variables may be "name"

Comment: @caddeveloper I tried to show that in my earlier comments.  If you had a macro system,  you'd be able to define a function defining macro that would define functions with access to their own names.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I can get simmilar effect by text editor. I use Notepad++ and snippets.

`(defun example () 
 (setq __FUNCTION__ "example" ) 
 (print (strcat "this is the name of my function: " __FUNCTION__) ) 
)`

Maybe that can be some solution
Thanks You all for help

Comment: @cadDeveloper I'm not familiar with AutoLisp, but that should probably be `(let ((__function__ ...)) ...)` rather than setq. You probably don't want to make __function__ a global...

Comment: yes `__function__` should be local, but it must be `setq` because in AutoLISP we don't have `let`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Let's look at two situations:

**1) You're writing the function.**

This should be easy, just define a variable that has the same name as the function and you're good to go. (As discussed in the comments above.)

You could even use something more descriptive than the actual name of the function. `(defun af () ...)` could be called "Awesome Function" instead of "af".

I would also recommend using standard constant value formatting: Capital letters with underscores to separate words. `(setq FUNCTION_NAME "AwesomeFunction")`. (This is just like `PI` which is set for you and you shouldn't change it - it's a *constant*.)

**2) You're calling a function that you might not know the name of until the code runs.**

Some examples of this:

```
(apply someFunctionInThisVariable '(1 2 3))

(mapcar 'printTheNameOfAFunction '(+ setq 1+ foreach lambda))

(eval 'anotherFunctionInAVariable)
```

To print the name of a function stored in a variable - like this `(setq function 'myFunction)` - you need to use the `(vl-princ-to-string)` function.

```
(vl-princ-to-string function)   ;; Returns "MYFUNCTION"
(strcase (vl-princ-to-string function) T)   ;; Returns "myfunction"

(princ
   (strcase 
      (vl-princ-to-string function)
      T
   )
)            ;; Command line reads: myfunction
```

The `(vl-princ-to-string)` function can be used on any type that can be printed and will always return a string. It's great if you don't know whether you have a number or a word, etc.

Hope that helps!

P.S. I first used this technique when I was writing a testing function. Send it a function and an expected value and it would test to see if it worked as expected - including printing the function's name out as part of a string. Very useful if you have the time to setup the tests.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the answer.  It either case mentioned, there is no magic method to get the name of a function.  You have to provide it somehow.  Maybe that's all CAD Developer wanted.

Comment: The function has to be provided in a variable or argument somewhere for you to use it, right? The second example above shows you how to access the name of the function provided without knowing it ahead of time. Or do you think the op was asking something else?

Comment: Well, in C++,  _ _ F U N C T I O N _ _ has the name of the function you are in.  I assumed that was what the OP was asking for.  I honestly have no idea what else could have been meant.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), `__FUNCTION__` is treated as a constant defined at the top of the function like in answer 1 above. I can understand it might save time to copy that around rather than typing out function names, but even in the example on that page it would have been easier to type the name of the function instead of typing `__FUNCTION__`. The answer above may take slightly more work, but it creates the same functionality: the ability to use the name of the function you're inside.

Comment: I think you are missing the entire point of `__FUNCTION__` or `__func__` .  "The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared *by the translator* as if...." (italics added by me).